# Issue while upgrading to latest sqldeveloper

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a 3 year old sqldeveloper `(Version 1.5.5)` installed on my Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. But, when i try to upgrade I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sqldeveloper
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sqldeveloper is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these steps helpful and they solved my problem:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You have the latest version of `sqldeveloper` available in that version of distributive that you have. You need to upgrade the distributive.

Comment: oh, so you meant that i need to upgrade the Ubuntu. That cannot happen. Our "IT" department doesn't allow it.